# The definition of "union" in Abelian Category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

The following  is a passage, which introduces the definition of regular spectral sequence,  from a book.

Suppose in the Abelian category $\mathcal{C},$ the direct sum of any family of objects exists. Then for any object $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and any family $A_{i}(i \in I)$ of sub-objects of $A$
we define $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_{i}$ to be the image of the canonical morphism $\bigoplus_{i \in I} A_{i} \rightarrow A .$

My question : 1. In a general Abelian category,  the direct sum of any family of objects may not exists, is it? Can one give some examples?

2. Why do we define the  $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_{i}$ as above? Why cannot define it set theoretically?

Any answers is welcome!

Comment: How about the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know about spectral sequences yet, but I hope the following clears things up a bit.

1. @AnginaSeng gave an example ($\mathsf{FinVect}_K$) of an abelian category lacking arbitrary coproducts. Maybe you want to restrict to finite families of subobjects or require the abelian category to be cocomplete?
2. Not all abelian categories have objects with underlying sets, e.g. the category $\mathsf{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$ of chain complexes on an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Hence defining things *set-theoretically* is not really possible. However, drawing intuition from the exact sequence
   $$0 \rightarrow \bigcap_i V_i \rightarrow \bigoplus_i V_i \rightarrow \langle \bigcup_i V_i \rangle \rightarrow 0$$
   in vector spaces, modules and alike it makes sense to define the subobject spanned by the family of subobjects as the image of the canonical map $\bigoplus_i V_i \rightarrow V$.

**Note** I like to reserve the notation $\bigcup$ for sets, as I find writing $\bigcup V_i$ confusing in the case of vector spaces etc. This is why I added a span $\langle \cdot \rangle$ symbol in my answer.